# Automated Date and time lotus domino

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

it is possible to automate time and date last modified, I have 4 text box, one is for the date have the formula `@Created` and the 3 have the formula `@Modified`. i want the 3 text box modified one at a time.

sorry for my English.

Comment: Let me see if I understand your requirement.  Please confirm if this is correct.  When the document is created, you want field1 set to Created datetime. The first time the document is edited, you want field1 to stay the same, and field2 to be set to the modified datetime.  The second time the document is edited, field1 and field2 stay the same, and field3 is set to a new modified datetime.  The third time the document is edited, field1, field 2, and field 3 all stay the same, and field4 is set to a new modified datetime.  Is this correct?

Comment: yes sir, i try to put 1 @created and 3 modified, its not working.

Comment: Are you aware that there is a hidden field called $Revisions that keeps a list of modified datetimes?  You could use the @Subset function to get the first four elements of the list.

Comment: im not but i will try it, thank you.

Comment: sorry, but can you give me some explanation how to do that?

Comment: $Revisions[1] is the first modification date/time, $Revisions[2] is the second modification date/time etc.

Comment: Yes.  Panu has given the subscript notation, which is even easier than @subset. Either way, you will need to check @If(@Elements($Revisions) >= to the subscript value to protect against errors when the list is shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  you're looking for Richard's solution try this:

1. Create a field

   - put a field on your form,
   - go to field properties
   - make the field computed for display
   - check "Allow multiple values" in the first tab,
   - then go the the 3rd tab and select in the field "Display separate values with" the value "New Line"
2. @Formula
   Put in the value property of the text field:

   @Subset($Revisions; 4)

this will give you the first 4 entries. If you want to get the last 4 entries, put a minus before the number:

```
@Subset($Revisions; -4)
```

Is this what you wanted??